# Why does this C pointer's deferenced value become its memory address

Tags: c, pointers

Wondering why when the function below runs, that *p and p are printed out as having the same value. My understanding is that when *p++ runs, this causes the address of p to increment by one, but why does this cause *p to also become the memory address.

I also tried running the code without the *(just p++) and the output is still the same, what is the significance of the `*` in this demo code from a lecture.

The output I'm getting is:

> 1606416248 1606416248

```
int main() {
    int *p; 
    int a = 4;
    p = &a;
    *p++;
    printf("%d %u\n", *p, p);
}
```

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior (more than once, I'm afraid). `*p` is no longer viable for dereference after the third line of `main()`. Don't try to make sense of the senseless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/364/undefined-behavior#t=201608290635413370595; read the "remarks" section first though

Comment: In case it's not clear, `*p++` increments `p`, not what `p` points to. In fact, `*p++;` is the same as `p++;`. Your compiler should have warned you that you aren't using the result of the expression. If your intent was to increment the value of `a`, then you need `(*p)++` or to make things much more obvious, `*p=*p+1`.

Comment: @user3386109 I think OP knows this `this causes the address of p to increment by one`

Comment: @SouravGhosh It **doesn't** cause the ***address*** of `p` to increment, it causes the ***value*** stored in `p` to increment. In other words, it changes what `p` points to. (There's no way to change the address of `p`.) In any case, it should be obvious that if the OP understood what `*p++` meant, then OP wouldn't need to ask this question. So I think the OP is really asking, "What does `*p++` mean?". (In case you're wondering, I neither upvoted nor downvoted your answer. I think the answer is incomplete, but still helpful.)

Comment: @user3386109 That's right, it should have been worded as _address pointed by `p`_. However, i think, the real problem for OP here is the output (which is UB, of course), `*p to also become the memory address`....

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `%u` is an improper format specifier for printing an address. You should use `%p` for printing an address, and cast the argument to `(void *)` . This alone is sufficient to invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then coming to

> *but why does this cause *p to also become the memory address.*

**[Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).**

When you do `*p++;`, you're running out of bound, as `p` points to a single variable, not an array. So, next dereference of the pointer `*p`, will be invalid memory access, causing UB. The output, thereafter cannot be justified in any way.